# RethinkDB query with group by date

Tags: rethinkdb

I have the following documents stored:

```
{
    "date": 1437429603126,
    "id": "7c578fe6-5eeb-466c-a79a-628784fd0d16",
    "quote": {
        "c": "+2.45",
        "c_fix": "2.45",
        "ccol": "chg",
        "cp": "1.89",
        "cp_fix": "1.89",
        "div": "0.52",
        "e": "NASDAQ",
        "ec": "+0.58",
        "ec_fix": "0.58",
        "eccol": "chg",
        "ecp": "0.44",
        "ecp_fix": "0.44",
        "el": "132.65",
        "el_cur": "132.65",
        "el_fix": "132.65",
        "elt": "Jul 20, 5:59PM EDT",
        "id": "22144",
        "l": "132.07",
        "l_cur": "132.07",
        "l_fix": "132.07",
        "lt": "Jul 20, 4:09PM EDT",
        "lt_dts": "2015-07-20T16:09:40Z",
        "ltt": "4:09PM EDT",
        "pcls_fix": "129.62",
        "s": "2",
        "t": "AAPL",
        "yld": "1.57"
    }
}
```

And looking to run a query that selects fields `quote.t`, `quote.l`, `quote.c`, `quote.cp` where `t` is `AAPL` order by `date`. The piece that is missing is grouping by multiple documents in the same day. The logic I need is take the oldest document where `quote.t = AAPL`. So basically there should only be a single document returned each day, and that document should have the greatest `date`.

Here is what I have so far, missing the grouping of multiple documents in a single day though.

```
r.db('macd').table('daily_closes').filter({
    'quote': {
        't': 'AAPL'
    }
}).orderBy('date').pluck('date', {
    'quote': [
        't',
        'l',
        'c',
        'cp'
    ]
})
```

Also, I have secondary indexes, how can I use those in the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by date, but you store day as epoch time. So you need a way to turn it into day and group. We can then `group` by that value, and sort the reduction array in desc order, then get the first element of that array with `nth`.

```
r.table('daily_closes').filter({
    'quote': {
        't': 'AAPL'
    }
}).orderBy('date')
.pluck('date', {
    'quote': [
        't',
        'l',
        'c',
        'cp'
    ]
}).group(r.epochTime(r.row('date').div(1000)).date()).orderBy(r.desc('date')).nth(0)
```

You may got something like this:

```
{
"group": Mon Jul 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 ,
"reduction": {
"_date": Mon Jul 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 ,
"date": 1437429603126 ,
"quote": {
"c":  "+2.45" ,
"cp":  "1.89" ,
"l":  "132.07" ,
"t":  "AAPL"
}
}
}
```

So let's reduce noise, we will `ungroup` it. Basically without `ungroup`, you are operating on sub stream of each group, when you `ungroup`, they become a single document. We also only care about data inside `reduction`, because that contains a single, first document. Here is the final query:

```
r.table('daily_closes').filter({
    'quote': {
        't': 'AAPL'
    }
}).orderBy('date')
.pluck('date', {
    'quote': [
        't',
        'l',
        'c',
        'cp'
    ]
})
.group(r.epochTime(r.row('date').div(1000)).date()).orderBy(r.desc('date')).nth(0)
.ungroup()
.getField('reduction')
```

Now, let's use index.

First, `filter` is slow, and limit to 100k document, `order` without index is slow. Let's switch to getAll with an index. But we cannot `order` with an index follow by a `getAll`. So we will use this trick:

Create an index for both value and using `between`:

```
r.table('daily_closes').indexCreate('quote_date', [r.row('quote')('t'),r.row('date')])
```

Now, we use between:

```
r.table('daily_closes')
.between(['AAPL', r.minval], ['AAPL', r.maxval],{index: 'quote_date'})
.pluck('date', {
    'quote': [
        't',
        'l',
        'c',
        'cp'
    ]
})
.group(r.epochTime(r.row('date').div(1000)).date())
.orderBy(r.desc('date')).nth(0)
.ungroup()
.getField('reduction')
```

I hope this helps.